# Getting "another version of this product is already installed..." in windows when trying to install a newer python version

Tags: python, windows

I am currently trying to install python 3.7.0 when I already have python 3.8.3 installed in my computer. When I try to do so, I get the following error:

[image]

Anyone know how to fix it or do I have to uninstall python 3.8.3 completely? If so, how can I do it cleanly?

All help is appreciated

Comment: I'm having this problem as well